# Why does haskell evaluate a in a >> b?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, operators, monads

The >> operator for Monads in haskell is often defined as

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
a >> b = a >>= \_ -> b
```

It can be used to print things like

```
main = putStr "foo" >> putStrLn "bar"
```

Why does the compiler not optimize away the value of `putStr "foo"` and just evaluate `putStrLn "bar"`? It doesn't need it so why compute it?

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't need it?

Comment: What (>>) does depends on your monad.  In the IO monad it's defined to combine the effects from both operands.  Exactly how this is done depends on the monad definition.

Comment: `[(),()] >> [1,2,3] ~> [1,2,3,1,2,3]`. Even for something simple and pure like lists, the first argument is needed, the result depends on it.

Comment: Have I understood right if I say that it doesn't need the value but the "structure" of `m a`, like in List where `a >> b` is approx. a `concatMap (const b) a`?

Comment: For lists (and `Maybe` and some others), yes it only needs the structure, not the contained values. For something like `State s`, I don't see how one could meaningfully speak of the "structure" like one can for lists; there, the state is (potentially) needed. In `ma >> mb`, the value of type `a` that `ma` returns is usually not evaluated (it may be, e.g. in `State s`, the state may depend on the value `put (if even n then [] else [n]) >> return n`, so when `mb` needs to evaluate the state, the value returned by `ma` is also evaluated). What parts of `ma` are evaluated depends on the monad.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I like to use the deliberately generic term "shape" for the portions of a `Functor`-y type that are neither constant nor parametric--the side effects of `IO`, choice of constructor in `Maybe` or `[]`, the state value in `State`, &c. This "shape" is exactly what `(>>)` retains and exactly what `fmap` leaves unchanged, so it's a useful concept for clarifying how things behave.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Chris said, it depends on the monad. `Identity` or `Reader` won't evaluate the part in front of `>>`, because they don't need it to compute the result. Other monads, like `Writer`, `Maybe`, `Either`, `State` or `IO` will.

Let's take `Maybe` as an example. `>>=` is defined as

```
Nothing  >>= _  = Nothing
(Just x) >>= f  = f x
```

So if we expand `>>` we get

```
Nothing  >> _  = Nothing
(Just x) >> y  = y
```

So `Maybe` must evaluate what's in front of `>>` to see if the result will be `Nothing` or `y`.

`IO` is purposely defined in a way so that the action is evaluated whether its result is needed or not (otherwise it would be just impossible to use).

Answer (score 6):

Huh? Of course it needs the value of `putStr "foo"`. It's evaluated in `>>=` - only the result of the action is thrown away, not the action itself if you want to think of monads as actions.

For example in a parser, that would mean throwing away the just parsed sequence - but it was still parsed, so the cursor is still being moved forward.

Comment: Compare with this expression, where haskell is smart enough to not try to find the last integer: `const "foobar" . last $ [1..]`

Comment: @ErikHenriksson Yes, because the definition of `const` does not use its second argument. The same is not true for `>>=`.

Comment: @ErikHenriksson You're mixing up the monadic action `putStr "foo"` and the value produced by the monadic action `putStr "foo"`. For instance, `return [1..] >> putStrLn "Hello World"` works just fine because the value `[1..]` is never evaluated, but `return [1..]` is.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the monad.  In IO is is evaluated. In Identity the first is not evaluated:

```
> import Control.Monad.Identity
> import Control.Monad.Trace
> let x = trace "x" $ return () :: Identity ()
> let y = trace "y" $ return () :: Identity ()
> runIdentity $ x >> y
y
()
```